# How to retrieve value from gridview in ASP.net using jQuery, when popup is displaying the value of perticular row of gridview

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Here I am showing this record in a popup when click the linkbutton of gridview, working fine. In the Popup I have one more button to get the `PlanstartDate` and `PlanendDate` value, I need these value for date comparison purposes.

My question is that how to get `PlanstartDate` and `PlanendDate` values when the user clicks the button that is on the popup?

```js
function displayData4Popup() {

      $(document).on("click", "[id*=lnkbtnPopup]", function () {
         $("#lblprjDesc").html($(".Ad", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
         $("#assignedby").html($(".Assign", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
         // $("#description").html($(".Description", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
         $("#planstartdate").html($(".PlanstartDate", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
         $("#planenddate").html($(".PlanEndDate", $(this).closest("tr")).html());

     });
 }
```

And this is my gridview

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="gvActionLists"  AllowPaging="true"  runat="server" AllowSorting="true"

    AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover"
     PageSize="10"
    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#337ab7" ItemType="WoodkraftERP.Entities.PMSO.ActionPlanner"


    SelectMethod="BindActionListGridView" OnRowDataBound="gvActionLists_RowDataBound">
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#337ab7" />
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPopup" runat="server"  Text="show"></asp:LinkButton>--%>

                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPopup" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-xs" runat="server"  ToolTip="edit" OnClientClick="return displayData4Popup();" CommandName=''  CommandArgument='<%#Item.ActionID %>' OnClick="lnkbtn_Click"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ></i></asp:LinkButton>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:BoundField   DataField="ActionDescription" ItemStyle-CssClass="Ad" HeaderText="Action Description"/>
          <asp:BoundField  DataField="PlanStartDate" ItemStyle-CssClass="PlanstartDate" HeaderText="Plan Start Date"/>
          <asp:BoundField  DataField="PlanEndDate" ItemStyle-CssClass="PlanEndDate" HeaderText="Plan End Date"/>
         <asp:BoundField   DataField="ActionType" ItemStyle-CssClass="ac" HeaderText="Action Type"/>
         <asp:BoundField   HeaderText="Staus"  ItemStyle-CssClass="success"/>
        <%-- <asp:BoundField   DataField="CreatedBy" ItemStyle-CssClass="Assign"  Visible="false"  HeaderText="Assigned By"/>--%>

     </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution after some research in stack overflow , instead fetching value of controls i fetched text , like 
 **$("#selecter").text();** and it works for me.